# "ls"-command not doing anything

Tags: command-line, ls

Doing "ls" gives me absolutely no response. No "command not found", no "permission denied", absolutely nothing. I'm really confused. Please help.

Info:
Running Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 on a Digital Ocean VM, 1 GB, 1 vCPU.

Comment: Add the output of `type -a ls; command ls -al`, please. It's probably because it has no output to give.

Comment: do you have any files in that directory?

Comment: That was it, thank you. I'm just a bit confused because before everything showed up without -a

Answer (score 4):

No output means there is nothing to show. It also tells you the command completed with *no errors*.

It was suggested in the comments that you use `ls -al` with

- -a = display all files, as without it certain files are not displayed, such as those that have a "." (fullstop) as their first character
- -l = long listing format

Other commands are also useful, such as

```
pwd
```

which will print the working directory (ie. your current directory) which makes the `ls` command more understandable, in that you know where you are and have some explanation as to the results you are viewing (*ie. in your case, why there are no files*).

Comment: If you think files were visible before, but no longer are - it could be you previously were using an `alias`, eg. `ll` or `la` which exist on my *Ubuntu18.04* box as *short-cuts* for `ls -alF` & `ls -A`.  Enter `alias` to view the alias commands you have available...