# sudo dpkg --configure -a, seems to show no pop up lines

Tags: dpkg, sudo, configure

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` command doesn't show any update on configuration and just shifts to the next line. I don't know whether this command is even working or not. If it's not working what would be a suitable remedy?

[image]

Comment: Same here, which is expected if nothing is misconfigured. Why do you expect it to show anything?

Comment: The default response for unix commands (thus POSIX & Linux) is to show no messages for everything is fine, and only show warnings or error messages. No return output is *good* for Unix, Posix & Linux (*though of course every programmer can decide to use their own standards, so you shouldn't assume that applies to everything; check the return value if you need confirmation, ie. `echo $?`*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ls"-command not doing anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037378/ls-command-not-doing-anything)